# Jquery html() not not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple js function:

```
 function changeContent(id, content) {
         $(id).html(content);
     }
```

which gets called on ajax callback. id is an id of a div, and $(id) does indeed find it.

On Chrome I get an unhandled exception that HTMLDivElement doesn't contain method html(), while on IE8 and FF simply nothing happens, although when viewing in degub, .html() does appear in the dynamic method list.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: No, I'm not passing the id with #. I've tried that, it returned null, now it actually returns something. Is there another problem??

EDIT again: seems I was doing something else wrong. I've put the # back, now it works.

Comment: Maybe an issue with jQuery. Make sure that it loads and works.

Comment: If you really are passing `'#myid'` (string) as `id` the element-search will work but I would not call the function head intuitive …

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try use jQuery(id) instead.

You are sure you don´t pass the id without "#" right?

Answer (score 2):

Are you passing simply the ID as a string? In which case I would think it's not truly being found, maybe try this?

```
 function changeContent(id, content) {
         $('#'+id).html(content);
     }
```

Comment: Yeah, as the code provided will search for all DOM-elements with name `id` and not the elements with id `id` (which the function this answer gives will search for).